# Running Keras model on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu

I'm running on Windows 10 and have installed CUDA 12.3

Keras = 2.15.0
tensorflow = 2.15.0

My models are just training on CPU, not on GPU. Also the code:

```
from tensor flow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

I get:

```
WARNING: tensorflow: From C: \envs\p311_deeplearning\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py: 2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecate
d. Please use tf.compat.v1. losses sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.

[name: "/device: CPU: 0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 14870411986114771269
xIa_global_id: -1
```

How can I manage that my GPU can be found and that I can train on it?
(GPU = NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti)

Comment: I also tried python 3.9 and tensorflow 2.10
--> Same result!

Comment: which GPU do you have?

Comment: NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti - it is supported for CUDA

Comment: Have you installed all the required CUDA and CUDNN packages?
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: @AlbinSidås Thx for your response. Yes, I have done that! CuDNN is also added to PATH.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

Installing Conda is only the first step. After that CUDNN has to be placed on the hard drive and the environment variables have to be set up. I missed the latter.

The following video describes to process better, than I could write it down:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEFKlRSd8Ic